# Ubuntu stuck on black screen while updating to 20.04

Tags: dell, 20.04, xhci-hcd

I tried to upgrade my previous version of Ubuntu to 20.04 and found that my computer had been sitting in this screen:

[53999.194469] debugs: File 'le_min_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!

[43999.194519] debugs: File 'le_max_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!

[44119.314689] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!

[44119.314722] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: HC died; cleaning up

It's been like this all night and I'm not sure how to fix the problem. Any suggestions? I'm on a Dell XPS 3965 running dual OS.